# How do I emit particles from a vertex group?

Tags: particles, vertex-groups

[image: Blender viewport]

Hey guys, I am trying to create a disintegration effect where i have an object that moves across the floating eye, that I call Carver. It "carves" into the eye animating a boolean difference from a subdivided sphere. I am using dynamic paint, the carver as a brush and the eyeball as a canvas, and the carver will add the vertices that it is carving to a vertex group, and that vertex group is supposed to emit particles. My problem is that the entire eye emits particles, not just the vertex group. I'm not sure where i am going wrong here. as you can see in this picture, it seems like the vertex group is proper, as you can see the blue, so i am assuming the problem is in my particle settings somewhere..

https://drive.google.com/file/d/19TD8tWCtTwBGlAxOz3cIKKSnMFQOEYxj/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: It seems your PS is placed before dynamic paint in the modifier stack...

Comment: I changed the order and its still showing the same